# How to set logging level from Command Line Argument in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, logging, command-line-arguments

I am trying to set this property as it was in command line in IntelliJ Idea in the run configuration

```
-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
```

but it isn't working for me. How can I set this logging level in IntelliJ in a dynamic way?

[image: IntelliJ run configuration]

I added it this way also with VM options:
[image: VMConfig]

but still don't get the changes in the logging level:
[image: logLevel]

Answer (score 0):

Use the **VM Options** field to specify it instead of the program arguments:

[image: VM Options]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I added it that way and still don't get the level Debug for the logs.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct property for the logging you need? Maybe try `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG`?

Comment: Not so sure, I am a noob about logging. I took that one because is what I found in the debug that was the logger name, and found some documentation about it.